# crear un dataframe en python desde una lista

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy intentando crear un dataframe desde una lista que me devuelve esta informacion:

```
 [Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=333970434, symbol='ESGV', exchange='BATS', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGV', tradingClass='ESGV'), position=1142.0, avgCost=52.7765556),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=238760476, symbol='ESGD', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGD', tradingClass='NMS'), position=954.0, avgCost=64.1715282),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=26653236, symbol='DVY', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='DVY', tradingClass='NMS'), position=292.0, avgCost=101.06176745),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=27638087, symbol='VO', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VO', tradingClass='VO'), position=50.0, avgCost=170.48881),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=27684036, symbol='VDE', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VDE', tradingClass='VDE'), position=99.0, avgCost=81.962902),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=225020107, symbol='TFI', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='TFI', tradingClass='TFI'), position=1109.0, avgCost=50.50644005),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=43645865, symbol='IBKR', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='IBKR', tradingClass='NMS'), position=2800.0, avgCost=39.4058383),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=26787475, symbol='TIP', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='TIP', tradingClass='TIP'), position=207.0, avgCost=115.00465265),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=46577293, symbol='BWX', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='BWX', tradingClass='BWX'), position=712.0, avgCost=28.57725195),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=15547816, symbol='LQD', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='LQD', tradingClass='LQD'), position=99.0, avgCost=124.4389121),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=313845618, symbol='ESML', exchange='BATS', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESML', tradingClass='ESML'), position=309.0, avgCost=27.38696345),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=31230302, symbol='VNQ', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='VNQ', tradingClass='VNQ'), position=137.0, avgCost=88.7322321),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=238760480, symbol='ESGE', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='ESGE', tradingClass='NMS'), position=1221.0, avgCost=33.994677),
 Position(account='DUC00074', contract=Stock(conId=338719585, symbol='EAGG', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='EAGG', tradingClass='EAGG'), position=1280.0, avgCost=53.3022901),
 Position(account='DU1766596', contract=Stock(conId=6604766, symbol='EEM', exchange='ARCA', currency='USD', localSymbol='EEM', tradingClass='EEM'), position=2500.0, avgCost=43.045),
 Position(account='DU1766596', contract=Stock(conId=43645828, symbol='BND', exchange='NASDAQ', currency='USD', localSymbol='BND', tradingClass='NMS'), position=-1250.0, avgCost=83.9115439)]
```

Y cuando la creo via:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
```

Me devuelve un df asi:
[image: df resultante]

¿Como deberia hacer, para poder visualizar toda la informacion en el df de manera correcta, para posteriormente seleccionar solo las columnas que necesito?

Edit: De manera correcta = cada coma, una columna.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 3):

Parece que tus objetos `Position()` pueden ser  una `namedtuple` a juzgar por cómo aparecen en tu lista de entrada, y cómo Pandas ha sabido "convertirlo" en un dataframe tomando como nombres de columnas los campos de la namedtuple y como valores de las celdas los correspondientes valores de cada namedtuple.

El problema es que aparentemente el campo `"contract"` era a su vez una namedtuple, de tipo `Stock()`, con otros campos. Pandas no expande "recursivamente" las estructuras de datos dentro de la lista, y por tanto la celda correspondiente muestra su representación como cadena (`repr`).

Si mi hipótesis es correcta y los valores de esa celda son también `namedtuples`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
final = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df.contract.to_list())],
                  axis=1).drop("contract", axis=1)
```

y el resultado sería:

[image: tabla final]

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente, existe una manera de hacer magia (no lo dudo). Pero voy a intentar ayudarte..
A mi se me ocurre que podemos abusar de funciones `lambda`. Este tipo de funciones "pequeñas", aplicarlo a una columna de un `df` nos puede ahorrar muchas lineas de código, en tu caso la columna en discordia es "contract". Opté por hacer esto:

Siendo honesto me parece horroroso el código, pero vamos a tratar de entenderlo.

Creo una columna llamada `aux` que se genera aplicando una función `lambda` que reemplaza la cadena `'Stock('` por `''` y luego reemplazamos `')'` por `''`. Esto lo que quiere decir es que eliminamos esos caracteres de nuestra nueva columna.

`cant` : es la cantidad de columnas que se van a generar porque es el resultado de aplicar `split(',')` a la columna `aux`. y mostrar la cantidad de "separadores" que se crean. al llamar al metodo `unique()` nos devuelve un solo valor(gracias a dios, sino sería otra complicación).

La linea del for, estamos iterando en un rango de 0 hasta la cantidad que nos devolvió `cant`. Y ahora la parte tediosa...

`df['aux'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[i].split('=')[0]).unique()[0]` : Aquí estamos tomando `'conId'` en la primer vuelta del `for` . Y en la segunda `symbol` . Al usar `unique()` nos va a devolver un solo elemento. Pasando en limpio, sería nuestro nombre de la columna.

`df['aux'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[i].split('=')[1])` : Es el resultado, Es lo mismo que el nombre de la columna, pero la posición "1" . Por ejemplo, al aplicar `split('=')` a la primera fila, nos devuelve: `['conId', '333970434']` donde `[0]` seria `conId` y `[1] '333970434'`. Espero que se haya entendido, no creo que sea la mejor opción, pero espero pueda servirte

```
df['aux'] = df['contract'].apply(lambda x:x.replace('Stock(','').replace(')',''))

cant = df['aux'].apply(lambda x:len(x.split(','))).unique()

for i in range(0,cant[0]):
    df[df['aux'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[i].split('=')[0]).unique()[0]] = df['aux'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[i].split('=')[1])
```